# Which MySQL configuration do I want for simple load balancing for a web application?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

We are building a small advertising platform that will be used on several client sites. We want to setup multiple servers and load balancing (using Amazon Elastic Load Balancer) to help prevent downtime.

Our basic functions include rendering HTML for ads, recording click information (IP, user-agent, location, etc.), redirecting traffic with their click ID as a tracking variable (?click_id=XX), and basic data analysis for clients. It is very important that two different clicks don't end up with the same click ID.

I understand the basics of load balancing, but I'm not sure how to setup the MySQL server(s).

It seems there are a lot of options out there: master-master, master-slave, clusters, shards.

I'm trying to figure out what is best for us. The most important aspects we are looking for are:

1. Uptime - if one server goes down, automatically get picked up by another server.
2. Load sharing - keep CPU and RAM usage spread out.

From what I've read, it sounds like my best option might be a Master with 2 or more slaves. The Master would not be responsible for any HTTP traffic, that would go to the slaves only. The Master server would therefore only be responsible for database writes.

Would this slow down our click script? Since we have to insert first to get a click ID before redirecting, the Slave would have to contact the Master and then return with the data. Right now our click script is lightning fast and I'd like to keep it that way.

Also, what happens if the Master goes down? Would a slave be able to serve as the Master until the Master was back online?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad and subjective to be a suitable one for this site, or any of the related sites.  There is no single "correct" answer because all possible solutions have inherent limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Amazon's managed database service, [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/), this will take a lot of the pain out of managing your database.

You can select the [multi-AZ option](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/) on your master database instance to provide a redundant, synchronously replicated slave in another availability zone. In the event of a failure of the instance or the entire availability zone Amazon will automatically flip the A record pointing to your master instance to the slave in the backup AZ. This process, on vanilla MySQL or MariaDB, can take a couple of minutes during which time your application will be unable to write to the database.

You can also provision up to 5 [read replicas](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/) for a MySQL or MariaDB instance that will replicate from the master asynchronously. You could then use an [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) (or other TCP [load balancer](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.5/howtos/haproxy.html) such as [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or MariaDB's [MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/products/mariadb-maxscale) for a more MySQL aware option) to distribute traffic across the read replicas. By default each of these read replicas will have a full copy of the master's data set but if you wanted to you could attempt to manually shard the data across these. You'd have to have some more complicated logic in your application or the load balancer to work out where to find the relevant shard of the data set though.

You can choose to promote a read replica into a stand alone master which will break replication to the master and give you a stand alone cluster which can then be reconfigured as to your previous setup (or something different if you want and just using the data set you had at the point of promotion). It doesn't sound like something you need to do here though.

Another option would be to use Amazon's own flavour of MySQL, [Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/), on RDS. Aurora is completely MySQL over the wire compatible so you can use whatever MySQL driver your application already uses to talk to it. Aurora will allow up to 15 read replicas and completely transparent load balancing. You simply provide your application with the Aurora cluster endpoint and then any writes will happen on the master and any reads will be balanced across however many read replicas you have in the cluster. In my limited testing, Aurora's failover between instances is pretty much instant too so that minimises down time in the event of a failure.